# How to release socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, pthreads

I'm making a little tcp server and it processes a number of requests via threads. 
When my server is shutting down he leaves unclosed sockets. 
How can I close them automaticaly or somehow release on new launching of my server? 
The number of sockets is big and I don't want to manage them by hands.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you close your application, all the sockets you hold will be closed by the operating system. File descriptors are ref counted in the kernel, when there is no more users of the socket, the associated resources will be freed (TCP sockets are finished, files are closed, etc).

Comment: You don't have any choice. You have to 'manage them by hand', unless you are using a language that has destructors. Your question isn't clear: are you perhaps talking about *ports* in the TIME_WAIT state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the sockets created? Within a new thread or before a thread is started? If it's within the thread, you could consider using pthread_cleanup_push() to install a handler that closes the socket (if it's still open) when the thread exits.

Answer (score 0):

When I dealt with sockets last time what I used to do is to launch various threads each managing a socket and then close them separately hence each variable in each thread contains the socket no. Sockets can be closed using close(s); where s is the socket.Even though when you shutdown the program the sockets are released by the runtime however it is a good practice to close the sockets so that they can be used by other programs.